# Is uttering others name than Allah Haram

Tags: allah, shirk, kufr

Once I had hurt in my leg and when got a hit in that place and  uttered "O mom". I believe that Allah is one and he has no associates. Will it be shirk if I had uttered others name than Allah without any wish to get help/forgiveness unknowingly?

Please someone help me I am very anxious about this matter.

Comment: Is screaming the name of Allah halal?

Comment: I meant uttering actually

Answer (score 0):

The realities the things that exist are called asbab and we can call them take help from them it is natural in life. Like you can ask your brother to fetch you water or you can ask your brother to help you with your studies, you can also ask your father for guidance in any matter.

Shirk is taking help form something that is not there in reality and you are believing that it has super natural power to reach and help you.

And from Hadees we know intentions are vital in deciding our actions. So definitely you didn't intend of shirk while calling your mom, it is ok if your intention was ok.